# How to get checkboxlist selected property as true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  my aspx page i am taking a checkboxlist control and populating data from database. But when i used to select the item and debug my code always selected property  used to come as false.How to solve this.
 My code is

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkProduct" Width="200px" Height="90px" runat="server"    
 RepeatDirection="Vertical" style="overflow-y: scroll;
                            overflow-x: scroll;">
                       </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code Behind

```
 for (int j = 0; j < chkProduct.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        //CheckBoxList chkProduct;
        foreach (ListItem list in chkProduct.Items)
        {
            if (list.Selected )
            {
                enquiryProducts = new Services.EnquiryProduct();
                enquiryProducts.IsDelete = false;
                enquiryProducts.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(chkProduct.Items[j].Value);
                enquiryProductList.Add(enquiryProducts);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please put the binding code aslo. There may be a region that you are binding on the page load.

Comment: please check that your page posback event when you are binding checkboxlist

Answer (score 1):

You can lose the checked state if you are databinding the list on postback. You want to make sure that when you databind the list you only do it if `Page.IsPostBack` is `false`.

Comment: List<CommonServices.Product> productList = commonClient.GetProductList(string.Empty, null, 1);
        chkProduct.DataSource = productList.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
        chkProduct.DataTextField = "ProductCodeWithName";
        chkProduct.DataValueField = "ID";
        chkProduct.DataBind();

Comment: Where do you execute that code? In the Page_Load? Try adding the full Page_Load (or whatever method you do the databinding from) into your original question. But you also want to make sure that code is wrapped in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack) { //your code }`. If you databind on postback you will lose any changes that are made to the list. It's like you are creating the list all over again.

Comment: I think you need to post more of your code in the question. Please try to put the full Page_Load method and the checkboxlist event handler method in there (or submit button, whatever fires the postback event). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Were are you binding the check-box list.

It it is on the page load then it should check for is not postback as follow

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  //put your binding code here
   List<CommonServices.Product> productList = commonClient.GetProductList(string.Empty, null, 1); 
   chkProduct.DataSource = productList.OrderBy(i => i.Name); 
   chkProduct.DataTextField = "ProductCodeWithName"; 
   chkProduct.DataValueField = "ID"; 
   chkProduct.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: do the changes in checkbox list persists after the postback?

Answer (score -1):

try this..
**set autopostback property to TRUE** of checkboxlist

Comment: what will happen if autopostback is true?